# Customise Beamer templates for RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I'm writing a beamer presentation using RMarkdown. I have selected a template from [this website](https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/). I really love the functionality of the template, however, I'd like to change the base colour closer to something matching my college. Is it possible to edit the yaml or style file somehow to do this?

I have the following yaml information for my Rmd file.

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "My name"
date: "06/03/2020"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 2
    toc: true
    theme: "Berkeley"
    colortheme: "seagull"
    fonttheme: "structurebold"
---
```

I'd like to make changes to the colour theme "seagull", which I assume must be included in RMarkdown files structure somewhere. Or can this be change using a style sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] that shows which theme you chose? Probably something like `\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=yourcolourname}` will already customise most things

Comment: Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz please see my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the seagull color theme, you can simply change most colours with `\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=yourcolourname}`

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "My name"
date: "06/03/2020"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 2
    toc: true
    theme: "Berkeley"
    fonttheme: "structurebold"
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: 
- \definecolor{yourcolourname}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
- \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=yourcolourname}
---

test
```

https://rstudio.cloud/project/1016900

Comment: Hi thanks this works well. Can I ask if you know if there is a list of \setbeamer commands? I'm particularly keen to change the grey margin colours to hunter green. Thank you.

Comment: @elliot To change the sidebar background: `\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=green}`. Most of these commands are listed in the beamer user guide (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) or a short overview http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf